# how to customise order notes in view order page in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, code-snippets

please could you help me to find
how to edit automatic order notes generated by system (related to items changed through the order ) i couldn't find it's file

what i want to do

- add quantity next to deleted item ( if i have 10 items in order and i have deleted 3 i want to see number of deleted in order notes
- add total after deleted or added

[image]

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm an ios developer and my own app is resting on woocommerce apis really i'm not php developer , so i looked for the file that i guess it should contain this function , to could guess the what i should do  but i didn't get it , so i asked for help--- and searched alot before asking :)

Comment: Sounds like you need a PHP developer. Since we are not a free coding service, you can hire a PHP WordPress dev on Fiverr for example! I'm sorry disappointing you, but I'm just following the rules here.

Comment: thanks , i made a job and i will share results here , thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
**Solution 1:**
add order note from checkout

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'woo_custom_order_notes_checkout_fields' );
function woo_custom_order_notes_checkout_fields( $fields ) 
{
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Your Special notes';
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Add your special note txt';

    return $fields;
}
```

When you place an order with custom text and after the order is placed you will be able to see custom order notes in order detail/edit orders on the dashboard.

**Solution 2:**

Get/ print order all notes on the order view/edit page after clicking on the update button.

```
// order comment/notes by id
function woo_get_comment_by_id( $comment_id ) {
    $comment = get_comment( intval( $comment_id ) );

    if ( ! empty( $comment ) ) {
        return $comment->comment_content;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post_shop_order', 'wpo_wcol_order_notes', 10, 1 );

function wpo_wcol_order_notes ( $order_id ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_id' => $order_id,
        'orderby' => 'comment_ID',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'type'    => 'order_note',
    // 'number'  => 1
    );
    remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments', 'exclude_order_comments' ), 10, 1 );

    $notes = get_comments( $args );

    if($notes){
        foreach($notes as $note){
            $comment_id = $note->comment_ID ?:0;
            if( $comment_id ){
                echo woo_get_comment_by_id( $comment_id ).'<br>';
            }
        }
    }
    exit; // after test you should removed
    add_filter( 'comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments', 'exclude_order_comments' ), 10, 1 );
}
```

You can also change the action "save_post_shop_order" accordingly as per requirements.

Comment: The screenshot comes from an order of the admin dashboard. The filter you suggested is part of the checkout.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i think you missed the question it's not part of checkout

Comment: @MahmoudQatamsh yes but as per our understanding, checkout note will show on dashboard order view/edit page.